# How to set up git instaweb on Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: ubuntu, gitweb

I am trying to get GitWeb work on newly installed system. I have already updated the system and installed git and lighttpd. But when I am running **git instaweb** everything that I see is

```
(configfile.c.426) Warning: mod_auth should be listed in server.modules before dynamic backends such as mod_cgi
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

and endlessly loading page in the firefox.

1. I tried to install the libcanberra-gtk-module and libcanberra-gtk3-module but it did't help.
2. Then I tried to install libcanberra-gtk* but it didn't help too.
3. Also I tried to change the browser to chromium and install firefox without connecting it to snap but the result stayed the same.

Is there a way to somehow solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

**git-instaweb** is a simple script to set up **gitweb** and a web server for browsing the local repository. You need to install gitweb(web frontend to Git repositories) to your system.

For example(Ubuntu): `sudo apt-get install gitweb`